# Benchmark: nginx1.8+php-fpm vs apache2.4+mod_php

Tags: linux, nginx, apache-2.4, benchmark

I'm benchmarking these two setups (installed on the same system)

```
nginx 1.8.0 + php-fpm (5.6.14-0+deb8u1)
apache 2.4.10 + mod_php (5.6.14-0+deb8u1)
```

Have runned through the output of `phpinfo()` and they look the same (haven't changed anything manually)

Hardware:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz + 16GB RAM
```

## Test 1 - one single HTTP (PHP) request once (no concurrency)

```
nginx ~= 360ms
apache ~= 320ms
```

## Test 2 - loading the website with all static content css/js etc

```
nginx ~= 7.7sec
apache ~= 8.9sec
```

What is it that I have missed in the configuration?

`AllowOverride All` is even set on apache and apache still outperform nginx on a PHP request!?

## nginx

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  8;
pid  /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    sendfile  on;
    tcp_nopush  on;
    tcp_nodelay  on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server_tokens  off;
    autoindex  off;

    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name  domain.com;

        root  /var/www/public/secure;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        # Add trailing slash
        rewrite  ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

        location / {
            try_files  $uri $uri/ @missing;
        }

        location @missing {
            rewrite  ^ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ .php$ {
            include  /var/ini/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass  php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/public/secure/index.php;
        }
    }
}
```

## apache

```
Listen 8080

<Directory /var/www>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public/secure

    #LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog /var/www_log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www_log/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: "Test 1 - one single HTTP (PHP) request once (no concurrency)" - this test is mostly irrelevant in practice. Test 50 simultaneous full page renders - you can quickly simulate it with curl or wget mirror. This is practical use.

Answer (score 0):

Outperform how? If this is set up like any other web request benchmark I've seen, then the *lower* the number, the higher the performance.  In that second case, your nginx installation was over 1 second faster than apache.  The second case is really the only one worth fussing over.

How many times are you running it for each benchmark?

Also, if you're getting 7.7 sec for one request on a phpinfo page, then that's concerning.  What are the rest of the hardware specs? What OS? What other services are running?

Comment: the 7.7 sec is from you request the website until its fully loaded with all static content like js and css.. apache is 40ms faster than nginx with a PHP request.. and `AllowOverride All` is even enabled (.htaccsss) If `AllowOverride All` is disabled apache will be even faster